# eXist-db serialize is expand-xincludes=no ignored?

Tags: xquery, exist-db

In eXist-db 4.4, Xquery 3.1, I am compressing a number of XML files to a .zip in a directory. The compression process uses `serialize()`.

The XML files have some large `xincludes` which [according to the documentation](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/xinclude) are automatically processed in serializing. I have attempted to 'turn off' the xinclude serialization in two places in the code (`prologue declare` and `map`), but the serializer is still outputting all xincludes:

```
declare option exist:serialize "expand-xincludes=no";
declare function zip:get-entries-for-zip() 
{
  (: get documents prefixed by 'MS609' :)
  let $pref := "MS609"

  (: get list of document names :)

  let $doclist := xmldb:get-child-resources($globalvar:URIdata)[starts-with(., $pref)]

  (: output serialized entries :)
  let $entries :=  
      for $n in $doclist
         return
            <entry name="{$n}" type='text' method='store'>
               {serialize(doc(concat($globalvar:URIdata, "/", $n)), map { "method": "xml", "expand-xincludes": "no"})}
            </entry>

   return $entries
};
```

The XML data with xincludes to reproduce this problem can be found here http://medieval-inquisition.huma-num.fr/downloads under the description "BM MS609 Edition (tei-xml)".

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`expand-xincludes` serialization parameter](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/xquery.xml#legacy-serialization) is specific to eXist and, as such (or at least at present), cannot be set using the `fn:serialize()` function. Instead, use the [`util:serialize()` function](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/util#serialize.2):

```
util:serialize($document, "expand-xincludes=no")
```

Alternatively, since you're ultimately interested in zipping the contents of a collection, you can skip the explicit serialization step, declare your serialization options in the query's prolog (or set it inline using [`util:declare-option()`](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/util#declare-option.2)), and simply provide the [`compression:zip()` function](https://exist-db.org/exist/apps/fundocs/view.html?uri=http://exist-db.org/xquery/compression#zip.2) the URI path(s) to the collections/documents you want to zip. For example:

```
xquery version "3.1";

declare option exist:serialize "expand-xincludes=no";

let $sources := "/db/apps/my-app/my-data" (: or a sequence of paths to individual docs:) ! xs:anyURI(.)
let $preserve-collection-structure := false()
let $zip := compression:zip($sources, $preserve-collection-structure), 
return
    xmldb:store("/db", "my-data.zip", $zip)
```

For more on serialization options in eXist, see my earlier answer to a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49290616/659732.

Comment: Well...that's much easier :)

Comment: BTW what does `! xs:anyURI(.)` this do in this context?

Comment: It casts the value(s) in `$sources` to be of type `xs:anyURI`, which is the required type for the `compression:zip()` function. Also, I've filed a feature request to expose these eXist-specific serialization parameters to the standard functions: https://github.com/eXist-db/exist/issues/2394. Thanks for pointing this out!